# Can dynamic backends be started dynamically in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I know the question has been asked before but I have not been able to find a definite answer.

I would like to use a dynamic backend to process tasks added to the default push queue. I would prefer to use a backend since I need the extra memory (1g vs 128m)

The questions [How do dynamic backends start in Google App Engine](/questions/6252337/how-do-dynamic-backends-start-in-google-app-engine) and [Starting and stopping Google App Engine backends](/questions/7221638/starting-and-stopping-google-app-engine-backends) both suggest that this cannot be done programatically while the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/backends.html#Types_of_Backends) and [GAE issue 5695](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5695) both suggests it can be done.

If yes - how? (The behavior I would like is that the dynamic backend starts when a task is added to the queue and stops when the queue is empty.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resident backends have to be started and stopped manually. Dynamic backends start automatically when they receive an HTTP request, and shut down after a few minutes of idle time.

To address a task to a particular backend, [specify a target](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Push_Queues_and_Backends):

```
taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker/', params={'key': key},
              target='1.backend1')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have studied this a bit further and my conclusion is that it the above description and the documentation are correct and working, but that one detail (not obvious to me) is left out. And that is that in addition to a) defining your backed in the backends.yaml and b) to explicitly updated the backend by using the appcfg command line tool, you also have to c) start the dynamic backend using the admin console. If you do not do that the task will not run. Once the dynamic backend is manually started it acts as described in the documentation.